# How to use Cross Linker instead of native linker

Tags: c++, c, linker, makefile

I am trying to cross compile a package for MIPS architecture using toolchain provided by OpenWRT. I come across following error during make:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/user/package/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/libz.so when searching for -lz
```

In this case zlib is already cross compiled for MIPS but make is using '/usr/bin/ld' instead of 'mipsel-openwrt-linux-ld'. I have tried ./configure with --with-ld option but it says that '--with-ld' is unknown option.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check following page, https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/crosscompile?

> Pass the host and build to the build system of the package to trigger cross-compile
>
> For GNU configure, use --build=architecture-unkown-linux-gnu --host=architecture-openwrt-linux-uclibc (for example: ./configure --build=x86_64-unkown-linux-gnu  –host=mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc)
>
> Run ./config.guess to get the --build= option.
>
> Check the output and ensure that 'checking whether we are cross compiling… yes' is yes.
>
> For GNU make, override the CC and LD environment variables (usually not needed if GNU configure was used)
>
> make CC=architecture-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc LD=architecture-openwrt-linux-uclibc-ld

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried steps you mentioned but that didn't work too. I guess there was some problem with ./configure script that was not able to set LD variables.

Comment: How about the last line `make CC=architecture-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc LD=architecture-openwrt-linux-uclibc-ld`? What kind of error did you get?

Comment: Tried but no success. Found some pre-built packages for this architecture so ended up my struggle.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this two years old. I had the same issue when building foreign packages for OpenWrt.

As for the most recent OpenWrt, you have set at least two ENV variables:

1. add your `Path_to_OpenWrt/staging_dir/toolchain-*/bin` path to your `PATH` ENV var
2. set your `Path_to_OpenWrt/staging_dir` to your `STAGING_DIR` ENV var

You should now be able to compile an autoconf based project with `AC_CANONICAL_HOST` (look it up in the configure.ac) with `./configure --host=architecture-openwrt-linux`.

You probably will need to set more ENV vars e.g. `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR` to make `pkg-config` work appropriately.

I have written a bash script which does all the work for you:
[sdkenv.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lnslbrty/openwrt/linksys3200ac-master/sdkenv.sh).
You can activate the script with `source sdkenv.sh` *before* configuring.